# typeorm) query builder, left join and delete

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I want to receive id and user information from the controller as arguments and delete it with query builder. But I am getting QueryFailedError: Unknown column 'certificate.id' in 'where clause' error. What's the problem?

```
@Entity()
@Unique(['url'])
export class CertificateEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  @IsUrl()
  url: string;

  @Column()
  valid_from: string;

  @Column()
  valid_to: string;

  @ManyToOne((type) => AuthEntity, (user) => user.certificates, {
    eager: false,
  })
  user: AuthEntity;
}
```

```
@Unique(['username'])
@Entity()
export class AuthEntity extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  email: string;

  @Column()
  username: string;

  @Column()
  password: string;

  @Column()
  signupVerifyToken: string;

  @OneToMany((type) => CertificateEntity, (certificates) => certificates.user, {
    eager: true,
  })
  certificates: CertificateEntity[];
}
```

```js
// service
  async remove(id: number, user: AuthEntity): Promise<boolean> {
    console.log(id, user.id);

    // error this point !
    await this.certificateRepo
      .createQueryBuilder('certificate')
      .leftJoin('certificate.user', 'user')
      .where('certificate.id=:id', { id: id })
      .andWhere('user.id=:id', { id: user.id })
      .delete()
      .execute();
    return true;
  }
```

I'm not familiar with the query builder. Why Do I Get QueryFailedError: Unknown column 'certificate.id' in 'where clause' Error?

Answer (score -1):

If it's still relevant. I never saw the solution to delete with use leftJoin.

try to use default delete(), where "id" it's "certificate.id"

```
this.certificateRepo.delete({ user: { id }, id: "id" });
```

it's just a fast example, rewrite to suit your case.

Or use 2 steps (I suggest it's a bad sulution)

```
const result = await this.certificateRepo
  .createQueryBuilder('certificate')
  .leftJoin('certificate.user', 'user')
  .where('certificate.id=:id', { id: id })
  .andWhere('user.id=:id', { id: user.id })
  .getMany(); // .getOne()

result.forEach((el) => this.repository.delete(el.id));
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to remove the alias from the where, and the where expression needs to provide a unique parameter, otherwise the :id in andWhere will override the :id in where.

```
await this.certificateRepo
    .createQueryBuilder('certificate')
    .leftJoin('certificate.user', 'user')
    .where('id=:id', { id: id })
    .andWhere('user.id=:userId', { userId: user.id })
    .delete()
    .execute();
```